# Move a Drupal Site to a New Folder or Public_Html

Tags: directory, drupal-8, public-html

I have recently installed Drupal8 on my hosting via automatic installation and the system installed Drupal under a subdirectory (e.g. www.example.org/drupal8) but I wanted to move drupal directly under public_html and visualize it directly on my site (e.g. www.example.org). I have followed the instructions in here (https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/move-drupal-to-a-new-folder/) but I can only get access to the main site not the other sites that I produced. Any recommendation is welcome.

Best...

Answer (score 0):

Empty cache under "../drupal/admin/config/development/performance" Clear all caches. -> If you have access to the database with phpmyadmin clear the cache files there and search for URL and change the old URL from your website to the new one.

Comment: thank you for your recommendations. I have already cleared all cash files in my database but it did not function. I could not find the URL, where is that actually? Is it in "settings.php" file?

Answer (score 0):

That URL you posted is for overwriting or moving site over (one site ) but you talk about other sites so I think have other sites and want reach different sites within same server.

You can’t see the other sites because you probably have one document root inside your web server and it’s pointed to your /var/www/public_html
And whatever site you place there will show up. 
In following examples see how the document roots are different and point to 2 different sites& urls.

Assuming you have access to Your web server files and conf.

Site1 example

/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName site1.com
ServerAlias www.site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site1-html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Site2 example:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName site2.com
```

ServerAlias www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site2-html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Check out

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-18-04/